# Vuex: правильное объявление комплексных объектов состояний с значениями по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

У меня есть хранилище с модулями. Вот структура:

[image: Структура]

Объявление хранилища:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production", //Защита от изменений не через мутациии
  modules: {
    navigation: navigation,
    crudForm: crudForm,
    toastBar: toastBar,
    progressDialog: progressDialog,
    loginForm: loginForm,
    auth: auth
  },
  getters: globalGetters,
  mutations: globalMutations,
  actions: globalActions,
  state: globalState
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== "login" && !store.getters["auth/isAuthenticated"]) {
    next({name: "login"});
  }else {
    next()
  }
});
```

В state.js (глобальном), описываются глобальные состояния, в нем я декларирую следующее:

```js
export default {
    loginForm: {
        title: "Авторизация",
        toast: "Пользователь авторизован",
        handler: {
            request: {
                url: "/internalauth/auth",
                type: POST,
                parameters: {
                    login: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    pages: [
    ...
    //... Много объектов со вложенными составными объектами, подобных  loginForm
    ]
}
```

actions модуля loginForm:

```js
 //loginForm/signIn (action)
 async signIn ({state, rootState, dispatch}) {
      let overlayTimeout = setTimeout(() => dispatch("progressDialog/show", null, {root: true}), 1500);

      console.log(rootState.loginForm.handler); //undefined


      await dispatch("auth/signIn", {
          handler: rootState.loginForm.handler,
          login: state.login,
          password: state.password
      }, { root: true });

      clearTimeout(overlayTimeout);

      dispatch("progressDialog/close", null, {root: true});
}
```

Мне нужно получить loginForm (глобальное состояние) в модуле loginForm, **вместе во ВСЕМИ вложенными объектами** (и их **значениями по умолчанию**).

Где бы я не пробывал получить это состояние, заполненными оказываются только поля title и toast, а handler всегда undefined.

Пробывал получать loginForm через rootState, mapState(в компонентах), rootGetters (оборачивал геттер на state.loginForm.handler), mapGetters(в компонентах), this.$store.state.loginForm, ничего не помогает, loginForm.handler всегда пустой.

**Что я не так делаю и как тогда быть? Объясните пожалуйта**. Просто аналогично, я получаю подобные комплексные объекты из массива pages, лежащего в глобальных состояний и у него все вложенные объекты получаются заполненными.

Если я правильно понимаю, vuex не делает handler реактивным, как это можно обойти? Я знаю, что мог бы явно инициализировать все эти состояния в init мутации глобальных состояний на старте приложения через vue.set(...), но это будет не удобно. Глобальный state.js у меня является чем то вроде глобальной конфигурации, в котором удобно быстро настраивать все окружение приложения

[**Посмотреть ДЕМО, где при аналогичном подходе значения у handler есть**](https://jsfiddle.net/oc5L4bp3/31/)

Comment: а если изменить ключ `handler` на какой-нибудь другой?

Comment: @Дмытрык хм, а что в vuex в каждом составном объекте есть handler? Эм, сейчас попробую

Comment: хз, но с учетом симптомов, наименование настроживает)

Comment: @Дмытрык нет, все также.Переименовал handler в test                                                                              async signIn ({ dispatch, state, rootState }) {
        let loginForm = rootState.loginForm;

        console.log(loginForm.test); //undefined

        await dispatch("auth/signIn", {
            handler: loginForm.test,
            login: state.login,
            password: state.password
        }, { root: true });
    },

Comment: а Вы можете выложить воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: @Дмытрык сам проект нет,  позже попробую набросать где-нибудь простой пример. Хотя... Мб быстрее будет найти готовый пример с vuex на фидле найти и добавить в глобал Стейт скопированный хендлер, а затем получить его через rootState в каком-нибудь действии в одном из модулей, если вас не затруднит (я ближ. Часы только на телефоне:( )

Comment: @Дмытрык сделал фидл проект. Ничего не понимаю, все аналогично и работает... jsfiddle.net/oc5L4bp3/31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причиной неправильного биндинга вложенных свойств было то, что имя корневого состояния совпадает с именем модуля, который присутствует внутри хранилища. Vuex хранит объекты состояний модулей внутри объекта state с глобальными свойствами

Т.е **НЕЛЬЗЯ** создавать **ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЕ СОСТОЯНИЯ**, корневые имена которых совпадают с именами модулей. В моем случае состояние loginForm, совпадает с именем модуля loginForm.